# how to set/draw chart with minutes in jqplot line chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, charts, jqplot, linechart

I want to draw chart dynamically..
depends of selection by user. below is screen shot for that..
[image]

in this I have doing something line this..

```
var plot2 = $.jqplot(div, mainArray, {
                            title:chartValue[1],
                            seriesDefaults: {
                                lineWidth:1,
                                markerOptions: { show:true, size:3 },
                                rendererOptions: {
                                    smooth: true
                                }
                            },
                            axesDefaults: {
                                labelOptions:{textColor:'#313233', fontSize:'11px',fontWeight:'Bold', fontFamily:'Arial'}
                            },
                            axes:{
                                xaxis:{
                                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                                    rendererOptions:{
                                        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                                        tickInset:0
                                    },
                                    //tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                                    tickOptions:{
                                        autoscale:true,
                                        fontSize:'10px',
                                        fontFamily:'Arial',
                                        angle:-90,
                                        formatString: dFormat
                                    },
                                    //min: minDate,
                                    //max: maxDate,
                                    tickInterval:timeInterval
                                },
                                yaxis:{
                                    min: 0,
                                    max: maxV.length > 1 ? parseInt(maxV) + ((parseInt(maxV)/10)): parseInt(maxV)+2,
                                    tickOptions: {
                                        formatString: '%d',
                                        fontSize:'10px',
                                        fontFamily:'Arial',
                                        showGridline: true,
                                        showLabel: true
                                    },
                                    base: Math.E,
                                    forceTickAt0: true
                                }
                            },

                            legend: {
                                show: true,
                                labels: legendNames,
                                //placement: 'outsideGrid'
                                renderer:$.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer,
                                location: 'ne',     // compass direction, nw, n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w.
                                xoffset: 10,        // pixel offset of the legend box from the x (or x2) axis.
                                yoffset: 10        // pixel offset of the legend box from the y (or y2) axis.
                            },

                            cursor:{
                                show:true,
                                style:'auto',
                                followMouse:true,
                                zoom:true,
                                looseZoom:true,
                                showTooltip:false
                            }

                        });
```

in this starting of time from 12.00. but i want it near to data. how that`s possible?

Note:

```
mainArray = data
dFormat = string format for date time
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to set the `min` property that you have commented out under `xaxis`.

Depending on how your `mainArray` is formatted you may be able to get the first date value with `mainArray[0][0][0]` or `mainArray[0][0]`. Or, you may have to set/pass the variable `minDate`.